# Libgdx TextField not receiving focus after resize

Tags: menu, resize, libgdx, textfield

I am currently working on programming a character creation page which passes user inputted text to my Account file. The TextFields draw and resize correctly (I presume this after I made a shaperenderer around the fields to try to figure out if their position wasn't moving correctly, which I think could still be the problem), they are working when tabbing through with setFocusTravel(true), but the fields will not update the KeyboardFocus with mouse clicks. My screen implements the InputProcessor and the stage is the main processor.

The problem has been that after resizing my screen (I am running the Desktop version, so hitting the maximize button or dragging the edges) I cannot begin typing in either of the resized TextFields by clicking on them (it does not set the focus or the CursorPosition). The textfield that was already being typed inside of continues to receive input after resize, tabbing will move the KeyboardFocus in both the non-resized and resized screen, but mouse clicks will not change/set the KeyboardFocus while in a resized screen. I was playing around with addListener to my TextFields and then having the click event do stage.setKeyboardFocus (desiredTextField) but this has not worked. I also tried moving some of the InputProcessor codes into the TouchDown/Up, Render, and Resize methods, but none of this has worked.

Is there a known issue with the LibGdx TextField? Is this something in my code? Is there something I have not added?

Below are the main portions of the code for my NewCharacterScreen() class.

Render:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(delta);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();
    stage.draw();
    batch.end();

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.ESCAPE)) {
        game.goMM();
    }

}
```

Resize is not being implemented, but Show is:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void show() {
    imageLoader = game.getIL();
    imageLoader.load();
    arkun = imageLoader.getArkun();
    theBlackEra = imageLoader.getBlackEra();
    menufont = new BitmapFont();
    stage = new Stage();
    skin = new Skin();
    skin.addRegions(imageLoader.getAtlas());
    style = new TextFieldStyle(menufont, Color.BLACK, null, null, skin.getDrawable("tfBG"));

    image0 = new Image(arkun);
    image1 = new Image(theBlackEra);

    textfields = new TextField[2];
    textfields[0] = new TextField("Username", style);
    textfields[1] = new TextField("Password", style);
    textfields[0].setFocusTraversal(true);
    textfields[1].setFocusTraversal(true);
    textfields[0].setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
    textfields[1].setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, imageLoader.getScreenWidth(), imageLoader.getScreenHeight());
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Vector2 coords3 = new Vector2(imageLoader.getScreenWidth(), imageLoader.getScreenHeight());
    stage.stageToScreenCoordinates(coords3);

    image0.setBounds(imageLoader.getScreenWidth()/2 - arkun.getRegionWidth()/2, 
            imageLoader.getScreenHeight()/2 + arkun.getRegionHeight(), 
            arkun.getRegionWidth(), 
            arkun.getRegionHeight());
    Vector2 coords4 = new Vector2(image0.getX(), image0.getY());
    image0.localToStageCoordinates(coords4);

    image1.setBounds(imageLoader.getScreenWidth()/2 - theBlackEra.getRegionWidth()/2, 
            imageLoader.getScreenHeight()/2 - theBlackEra.getRegionHeight()*2.5f, 
            theBlackEra.getRegionWidth(), 
            theBlackEra.getRegionHeight());
    Vector2 coords5 = new Vector2(image0.getX(), image0.getY());
    image0.localToStageCoordinates(coords5);

    textfields[0].setBounds(imageLoader.getScreenWidth()/2 - imageLoader.getTFBG().getRegionWidth()/2, 
            imageLoader.getScreenHeight()/2 - imageLoader.getTFBG().getRegionHeight()/2, 
            imageLoader.getTFBG().getRegionWidth(), 
            imageLoader.getTFBG().getRegionHeight());

    Vector2 coords = new Vector2(textfields[0].getX(), textfields[0].getY());
    textfields[0].localToStageCoordinates(coords);

    textfields[1].setBounds(imageLoader.getScreenWidth()/2 - imageLoader.getTFBG().getRegionWidth()/2,
            imageLoader.getScreenHeight()/2 - imageLoader.getTFBG().getRegionHeight()*1.5f, 
            imageLoader.getTFBG().getRegionWidth(), 
            imageLoader.getTFBG().getRegionHeight());

    Vector2 coords2 = new Vector2(textfields[1].getX(), textfields[1].getY());
    textfields[1].localToStageCoordinates(coords2);

    stage.clear();
    stage.addActor(image0);
    stage.addActor(image1);
    stage.addActor(textfields[0]);
    stage.addActor(textfields[1]);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar problem (hud created with a stage resized properly, but buttons werent working after resize)

I dont know if you found a solution, but just in case you still need help and/or someone else has the same problem:

it seems that if you resize the game the inputProcessor is not updated (or sth, dunno).
What helped me was reinitializing the hud in resize(). I'm using an inputmultiplexer, so first I removed the hud Stage from the multiplexer, then I disposed the stage, initialized it again and added it to the multiplexer again (or set it as the inputProcessor). Works for me :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I never did manage to fix it. I ended up building my own textfield class and it has worked well for me. I may give your suggestion a try though, would help solve other issues down the road I am sure.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
   stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}
```